# ASP.NET Web Forms call embedded VB Code from another aspx. page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I got a Project where somehow an Method is called from another aspx.page. I want like to know how this work.

For instance, in my Foo.aspx I got this:

```
<script runat="server">
  Sub ShowHint()
   some code
  End Sub
</script>
```

in Bar.aspx I got this:

```
<script runat="server">
  ShowHint()
</script>
```

But how does this can even work? I dont get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript (AJAX) to get the data from a different page.
It is easy to do with the jQuery Load function.

You can also define classes where you can define subs of function which you can call from every webpage.

Is the webpage inside of you project?

An easy example: I have a file test.aspx and I want to load some data from test2.apsx. To load the data I use jQuery.

Here is test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$("#presenter").load("test2.aspx" ... = loads the content of test2.aspx into the div with id = presenter
        //$("#presenter").load("test2.aspx #content" ... = loads onlay the content of the div with id = content from text2.aspx
        //{ message01: "Hello", message02: "world" } = are the paramter I pass to test2.aspx          
        $("#presenter").load("test2.aspx #content", { message01: "Hello", message02: "world" }, function () {
            //here you can place code which will run after the load is completet
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="presenter"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is test2.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="test2.aspx.vb" Inherits="test2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="content" runat="server">
        </div>
</form>
```

And the code from test2.asp

```
Partial Class test2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles form1.Load
    Dim msg01 As String = Request("message01")
    Dim msg02 As String = Request("message02")
    Me.content.InnerHtml = msg01 & " " & msg02

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I know that I can define javascript classes and call functions from there but how I can do this with two .aspx pages? Its seems that one .aspx page operate like a helper class. Its a blank page and contains only vb-code in <scrip runat="server"> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this. Just have to include my "Helper" aspx-file in to another aspx-File:

```
<!--#include virtual="somefilename"-->
```